# How to print the cluster command in the log before executing it?

Tags: snakemake

I am using snakemake 7.32.3 on a cluster. I have set the `cluster` parameter to a complex command with wildcards in my configuration file. Now the cluster command fails, and snakemake outputs the error produced by the cluster command. However, that error message tells me nothing, as the cluster scheduler I am using is rather old. To debug this, I would need the exact command that snakemake uses to schedule cluster tasks.

I have tried running snakemake with `--verbose`, but it does not log the cluster command. Is there a way to make snakemake print this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `--dry-run` (or `-n`) allows seeing the shell command that snakemake would submit to the cluster. This might help in your case.

```bash
snakemake --dry-run ...
```

Comment: As I understand it, the OP wants the cluster command, so something like `sbatch --mem=1G -o slurm/my-rule.1234.out ...`. `dry-run` gives you the rule's shell command, not the cluster's command. Or am I missing something? In fact, this would be a nice feature to have.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting! I was thinking about shell command, and thought that would be sufficient, but not sure about the `cluster` command/parameter.

Comment: @dariober is right. I guess this is just not supported...